# Way to automatically pause/continue all processes at a breakpoint using VSCode Multi-Target debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, multiprocessing, gdb

Currently I have a few processes which I am trying to debug using VSCode's debugging extension which uses GDB. Each process makes calls to other processes and they all have a timeout period. The issue is that when I reach a breakpoint at one process, the other processes continue and will eventually timeout making it difficult to debug. The only workaround I have is to quickly go and pause each of my processes manually when I hit a breakpoint which often doesn't work and is inefficient. Does anyone know of say a launch.json setting I could add to vscode to make it so all the processes automatically pause and continue at the same time when a breakpoint is reached?